# ffmpeg video crossfade error

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

Following the code in this elegant [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1001039/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-do-a-video-crossfade-with-ffmpeg) from Mark [Gerolimatos](https://superuser.com/users/423986/mark-gerolimatos), I have this script:

```
in1="b1.mp4"
in2="b2.mp4"
out="finish.mp4"

ffmpeg -i $in1 -i $in2 -an -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=0:1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[firstclip];\
[1:v]trim=0:1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[secondclip];\
[0:v]trim=1:3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeoutsrc];\
[1:v]trim=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeinsrc];\
[fadeinsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadein];\
[fadeoutsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadeout];
[fadein]fifo[fadeinfifo];\
[fadeout]fifo[fadeoutfifo];\
[fadeoutfifo][fadeinfifo]overlay[crossfade];\
[firstclip][crossfade][secondclip]concat=n=3[output]" \
-map [output] $out
```

I am getting the errors:

```
[NULL @ 0x7f8b33806200] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' '
 : Invalid argument
./myScript.sh: line 18: -map: command not found
```

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Looks alright. Format it as a single line and execute.

Comment: Ah, my fault. Missing a line ending, you were correct @mulvya.